# Getting the first element of a list in Map<String, List<String>> in a JSP

Tags: java, list, jsp, hashmap

I have a page that I did not build the backend for. I would collapse the list to just a string because it seems unnecessary, but it is embedded quite a bit and can't really be refactored because it is used somewhere else. So right now when I try to

```
<s:if test="%{station.wInfo != null && station.primaryLocation}">
   &nbsp;<s:property value="%{station.code}"/>
   <s:iterator value="%{station.Locations.values}" var="loc">/<s:property/></s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

The output is a list with brackets. Since it is just 1 element it looks like [something]. What is the best way to get the first element of the list. I can iterate the keys okay just not the values since it is a list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the first element of a list is `list.get(0)`, ensuring first that the list is not empty.